# How to make jssor captions appear on mouseover only?

Tags: javascript, jssor

I'm creating a page with a jssor slider.  The slider will have thumbnails and a caption will appear at the bottom of each picture.  I have $AutoPlay set to false.  Right now, the caption transition is set to MCLIP|B-FADE, and it slides up after the picture comes into view.  What I would like is for the caption to appear only on mouseover over the picture, and have the caption close upon the mouse moving off the picture. I haven't been able to find or figure out a way to do this.  Does anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .slide .caption {
        display: none;
    }
    .slide:hover .caption {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<div u="slides" ...>
   <div class="slide" ...>
       <div class="caption" ...></div>
   </div>
</div>
```